# can you please recommend reverse pinout NPN transistor with SOT23 package

Tags: transistors

Standard pinouts of transistor looks like this[image]

The Question is I want a NPN transistor with emitter and collector swapped? please share part number you aware of this type.

Comment: General purpose? RF? What are you going to use it for? Or - what's an equivalent part?

Comment: bend the leads the opposite direction and solder it upside down  and rotated

Comment: @ErikR, I want it for general purpose. (equivalent part is BC847).

Comment: @yugi By the reel? Or just a one-off? Because if just a one-off, then Jasen might be right about it.

Comment: @Jasen,@Jonk- thanks but i want this component large quantities so i cannot use it by bending pins.

Comment: Why do you want such a thing? I am not trying to challenge you. I am just having trouble figuring out the use case. The only thing I can think of is that maybe you made a bunch of PCB's with incorrect pinout for a transistor, so you are trying to find a part you can use instead of scrapping the PCB's.

Answer (score 4):

One of the nice things that happened on the transition from TO-92 transistors to SOT-23 is that the pinouts became overwhelming standardized, rather than the three previous common permutations. Unfortunately that makes it more difficult to fix a PCB error or similar situation.

Although technically not exactly what you are requesting, the [2SC3326](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/2SC3326_datasheet_en_20201120-1916336.pdf) will function in reverse as an NPN transistor as requested with 25V rating and typical hFE of 150 since it is designed for muting applications in professional and other audio gear.

Not too expensive, though obviously not as cheap as a jellybean NPN.

---

To clarify a bit further- all BJTs will work (to some extent) as transistors with the E and C swapped. A random sample of BJT I have here (C8050) has a measured hFE of 130 in the forward direction and the BVceo is 25V according to the datasheet. In the reverse direction, the measured hFE is only 22 and the minimum breakdown voltage is 6V according to the datasheet (actually it will be a bit higher). So it will work reversed but not very well. The C3326 is designed to be more symmetrical so the gain is a more is a more usable number (150) in the reverse direction and the breakdown voltage is relatively high at 25V guaranteed (most jellybean transistors in reverse have a rated BVebo of 3-6V). So you can think of it as a 25V transistor with \$\beta \approx\$150 when used with C and E swapped.

Comment: thanks, In 2SC3326 (transistor u recommended) also has standard pinouts as i mentioned in picture, can u tell how this will be solution for me?

Comment: It works in reverse (emitter/collector swapped) as I described above.

Comment: @yugi, this is almost like a bidirectional transistor. Emitter and collector are (sort of) interchangeable.

Comment: dog slow, but a very interesting device!

Comment: A fun answer. Long ago I had great problems with a transistor working too well in reverse mode. Details escape so far but memory of the pain remains :-).